# How do I modify default labels of the location module?

Tags: entities, location

How can I modify the field names of the location widget that I use to collect addresses and phone numbers. I am using Drupal 7 with the Location Module: https://drupal.org/project/location

Below a screenshot of the fields I would like to rename ('Street Location' to 'Address Line 1' as an example).
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You need to update your question to actually specify what modules you're using. As of now, it's anyone's guess. All I know is this isn't Address Field, so I've removed that tag.

Comment: @RyanSzrama Thank you for pointing this out. I am using the Location module drupal.org/project/location. I updated the description and the title. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.drupal.org/node/381458#comment-6699162 worked for me

```
/**
 * Implements hook_location_element_alter().
 */
function update_personal_info_location_element_alter(&$element) {
  $element['additional']['#title'] = "Address line 2";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The *location* is essentially a custom table `location` in the database with all those columns (ew). Having looked through the code they make Drupal form elements for each column in the table as needed.

I suggest [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to simply change the title disabled where needed when displaying the `location` on page forms.

there are a zillion examples here on stackexchange of how to use hook_form_alter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the suggestion.

There are various options to do so.

1. Use "String Overrides" module
2. Make a module that implements hook_form_alter() to change the help text.
3. In location.module, change:
   '#title' => t('Street Location'),
   to
   '#title' => t('Address Line 1'),

Though 3rd one is not best practices since it makes updating the module harder.

Let me know if you face any query/concern regarding this.

Thanks!

Comment: hook_form_alter is not working.b/c field title is not avalable their